# How to make event registration form fields be displayed inline

Tags: civievent, display, online-registration

At the moment, each field specified in a profile that is related to an event online registration form, has its own line, inside its own div.
I want to be able to display 2 specific fields in the same line, which are logically connected to each other.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on Drupal you could do the event registration using a [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) with [webform_civicrm](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm) and use the [webform_layout](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_layout) module to place two fields on the same line.

Alternatively you could write a tiny [extension](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/master/extensions/) to drop in some jQuery to move the fields around in the standard event registration form. There is write up of how to do that here: http://jackrabbithanna.com/articles/easy-jquery-modificaiton-civicrm-forms  Note that since that was written `cj` [has been deprecated](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Javascript+Reference#JavascriptReference-Globals.1) in favour of `CRM.$`

If you can do the changes with CSS without needing the power of jQuery, you can also do that - see my answer to [How can I change the way price set information is presented on a contribution page?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19132/how-can-i-change-the-way-price-set-information-is-presented-on-a-contribution-pa)