# How can I change the way price set information is presented on a contribution page?

Tags: price-sets, templates, custom-templates

Contribution pages showing price set information (i'm using a radio button field with various options to choose from) show the various price option with the label text first, in bold, and then the amount, not in bold, and with a space between the currency symbol and the amount.

I'd like to have the amount first, with no space between currency symbol and figure, followed by the label text.

I'm assuming all this is in a template file somewhere? If so, where should I be looking? Anything else to look our for or take into consideration?

Comment: The layout (order of label, symbol, amount) is I believe determined in CRM/Price/Form/PriceSet.tpl  You can override it as civicrm documentation discusses and put a different version in files/civicrm/custom_tpl    That template is also used in Event Registration.

Answer (score 1):

You can do most/all of that with an extra CSS file.  Go to `Administer > System Settings > Resource URL's` and enter a value for the `Custom CSS URL`.

In that file, you can add CSS to change the default appearance.  To figure out what to put there, you'll need to examine the page and experiment with Firefox/Firebug or similar.  There are lots of CSS tutorials around, but if you post a URL of the current version someone might suggest some CSS for you.